# androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0 Depenceny Error Appeared Without Any Modification?

Tags: android, android-studio

While runs/builds working properly, Android studio started giving this error since a few hours. Btw I'm sure that i never add/modify any dependency on project.

```
Execution failed for task ':app:checkPrepReleaseAarMetadata'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckAarMetadataWorkAction
   > The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
     dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
     is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30).
     Dependency: androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0-alpha02.
     AAR metadata file: /Users/userxyz/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/cefbfad6ef180119f5f4851a3efddbb7/jetified-core-ktx-1.7.0-alpha02/META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties.
```

What i’ve tried:

1. Invalidate caches and restart
2. Re-download project and add to studio again

Android studio version, Arctic fox 2020.3.1

Answer (score 5):

I have also face this issue with **androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0** than downgrade to **androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0** and its working fine and there is same problem with

```
'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your project's `minCompileSdk` is `31` but `core-ktx` uses `30`. Try to downgrade your project's `minCompileSdk` to `30` and see if it solves your problem or not.

Comment: If you still wish to use compileSdk 31 then I think the alpha versions of the core dependency already support 31. Android 12 is SDK 31 and maybe Google is gearing up for a stable release soon which is causing these issues

Comment: Nope, app's minCompileSdk is 17. Seems the ver. 31 comes from internal dependencies.